# Python - ImportError: No module named cy_ipc

Tags: python, python-2.7, graphlab

I'm trying to get started with Python `2.7`. I've the program installed as well as some packages , including `graphlab`, and I can do some basic operations , however, when i try to import packages to my code i got an error.

My code is :

```
import graphlab as gl

##I got the folollowing error:
    import graphlab as gl
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\graphlab\__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    import graphlab.connect.aws as aws
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\graphlab\connect\aws\__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
    from _ec2 import get_credentials, launch_EC2, list_instances, set_credentials, status, terminate_EC2
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\graphlab\connect\aws\_ec2.py", line 17, in <module>
    import graphlab.connect.server as glserver
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\graphlab\connect\server.py", line 6, in <module>
    from graphlab.cython.cy_ipc import PyCommClient as Client
ImportError: No module named cy_ipc
```

I've googled changed my **PYTHONPATH** and **PATH** (PythonPath is included) but it's still not working.

```
PYTHONPATH = C:\Python27\;C:\Python27\Scripts;C:\Python27\lib;C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages;C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\graphlab;
PATH=.;%PYTHONPATH%;....
```

I tried several solutions, but none have worked.

I'll appreciate some help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your PYTHONPATH shows that you are on Windows.  GraphLab Create does not support Windows currently.  Interesting that the error came out that way, but this is probably because cy_ipc is the name of one of several packaged so's in the GraphLab Create package, and Windows wouldn't recognize those...hence it's not found.

Windows support is coming soon though.  In the meantime, Dato distributes a VM for Windows users: https://dato.com/products/create/virtual_install.html